# How to get Z attribute of point using Python and ArcGIS Desktop 9.3?

Tags: python, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-9.3

I am making a python code for arcgis 9.3. In this code i create a new point with x,y and z attributes as following :

```
rowsLine = gp.updatecursor(line_Feature_Class)
rowLine = rowsLine.next()

rowsPoint = gp.InsertCursor(point_Feature_Class)
feat = rowsPoint.NewRow()

while rowLine:

    #...

    ptObj = gp.CreateObject('Point')
    ptObj.x = xPremierPoint
    ptObj.y = yPremierPoint
    ptObj.z = zPremierPoint
    feat.Shape = ptObj
    rowsPoint.InsertRow(feat)
```

I want to add the z value in a field "zvalue" in my "point_Feature_Class". The problem is  i can't use an insert cursor (rowsPoint) and an update cursor at the same time.

So, at the end of the code, I want to delete the insert cursor, create an upsdate cursor, to loop in my "point_Feature_Class" and get the z attribute of each point and add it in the fiels "zvalue".

The code should be something like that :

```
rows = gp.updatecursor(point_Feature_Class)
row = rows.next()

While row :

    Zvalue = #???? row.shape.getz ????
    row.SetValue("zvalue", Zvalue)

rows.updateRow(row)
row = rows.Next()
```

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it this way:

```
row.GetValue("your_shape_field_name").GetPart().z
```

And [here](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Reading%5fgeometries) you can get more information and a complete example from the ArcGIS Desktop Help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! Now i have a new problem : The value return by this line is 1.#QNAN. It means that no value is set to point.z while i set the vaue prviously : `ptObj.z = zPremierPoint`. And if i try with .x, it works !

Comment: Does your feature class allows Z values?

Comment: Actually no ^^^I changed it and it's work.